# Finding correct bounds for double integral

Tags: calculus

I have the region $A = \{(x,y) \mid 0<x<2, y>0, y< 1 - \frac{x}{2}\} $. I want to integrate over this region such that $x>y$.

My function $f(x,y) = 1$ on $A$. It is $0$ otherwise.

What the bounds of my double integral?

I am unsure of how to make sure that $x>y$ in my boundaries.

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram?

Comment: @IanMiller Drawn a diagram of the region? It is a triangle. I'm not sure how that helps me figure what the boundaries should be.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. Does your diagram include all conditions stated, including the $x>y$ condition? What are the vertices of your triangles?

Comment: @IanMiller http://imgur.com/ioCS44G

Comment: So this shows us that the region enclosed by the triangle is from the inequalities $0<x<2$ and $0<y<1 - \frac{x}{2}$. How do I impose the $x>y$ requirement into my drawing?

Comment: You "want to integrate over [the] area such that $x>y$" so you only want part of the area which satisfies that inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial area $A$ is further restricted by the inequality $x>y$. Drawing the region and including the extra inequality gives you a triangle with vertices: $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$ and $\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$. So the integral will be:
$$\int_0^\frac{2}{3}\int_0^x f(x,y) dydx+\int_\frac{2}{3}^2\int_0^{1-\frac{x}{2}} f(x,y) dydx$$
Note: As $f(x,y)=1$ you don't need to evaluate the integral. You can just work out the area of the triangle.

Comment: Ian, can you please tell me how you find that triangle within $A$ explicitly?

Comment: Add the line $y=x$. You want the part where $x>y$. So the lower part in your diagram.

Comment: Ah of course! This makes sense. For your geometrical approach, i.e, calculating the area, why does $f(x,y)=1$ allow us to do this?

Comment: An integral is 'adding up' the value of $f$ over the area. As $f$ is 1 the 'adding up' will just calculate the 'area'. Compare to the 1D case of $\int_0^{10} 1 dx$ you'll just get 10. In your 2D case you are working out a volume where $f(x,y)$ is your z direction so its a triangular prism with height of 1.

Comment: Hm, okay. Can you explain what is geometrically happening with our double integrals? I think I understand what is happening, but I would like it to be clearer. $\int_{0}^{x} f(x,y)dy$ goes from the bottom of our triangle to  where it hits $y=x$. Then the outer integral takes us to $x=\frac{3}{2}$. After that we have to change our bounds up since we now hit $y = 1-\frac{x}{2}$ on our head. The outer integral of this takes us to the end $x=2$.

Comment: Yes thats correct. As the upper bound changes sharply at $x=\frac{2}{3}$ I've split the area into two right triangles.

Comment: Couldn't we have done this with summation of just two regular integrals? Our region is two dimensional. i.e, why is our answer not $\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{3}}xdx + \int_{\frac{2}{3}}^{2}1-\frac{x}{2}dx$ ?

Comment: To get that expression you have done the inner $(y)$ integral for each half as they are in the form $\int_a^b 1 dy$. Had $f(x,y)$ not been trivial then the double integral approach would be more meaningful.

Comment: Ian, i'm going to add my interpretation of what is going on soon.

Comment: http://imgur.com/ii0kLbm It makes sense now Ian. Thanks